# Is there a way to iterate/recurse through a Binary Tree by using an index?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, binary-tree, nodes

I've made a function in C that looks for nodes in a binary tree by "index". This is for cases where I need to go through every node and compare the contents with something. For the cases where I know what I'm looking for and just need the node returned, I have a find() method that is working.

```
void* getFromBT(BTNode* bt, int index) {
    static int count = 0;
    if (bt != NULL) {
        if (count <= index) {
            getFromBT(bt->left, index);

            if (count == index) {
                return (bt->data);
            }

           count++; 

           getFromBT(bt->right, index);
        }        
    }
    return;
}
```

However, in this method, at index 2 and beyond, I get a segmentation fault. I believe it's because of the blank return if the current node was found to be null, but the method performs the exact same without it. Changing the location of count++ varies the performance a little bit and the current placement of the line is where I get the most out of the method. Could someone please point out what is going wrong in this method since I don't understand it anymore and have been stuck on it for a while now?

TIA!

Comment: may not be the reason for your problem, but you should not have just `return;`, you should have `return NULL;` for invalid cases

Comment: You're right but it doesn't make the method work :(

Comment: `return (bt->data);` happens only for the deepest of the recursive calls and calling function doesn't check return value from if.

Comment: What can I do to solve that or break the recursion in that case then?

Comment: The `static int count = 0;` construct means you can only make one top-level call to the function — there's no way to reset the counter back to `0` for subsequent uses.  You'll need to eliminate that.  You need to heed the return values from the recursive calls.  You appear to be doing an in-order traversal to sequence the nodes.  This will get increasingly expensive as you use bigger values of `index`.  Searching for each index from 1 to N will yield quadratic performance.

Comment: You can store extra value 'count' in node, which will mean no of nodes below it(left+right+1(this node)). Then you can compare count with index and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try This
You can store extra value 'count' in node, which will mean no of nodes below it(left+right+1(this node)). Then you can compare count with index and work from there

```
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct *Node left;
    struct *Node right;
    int count;
}BTNode;
int *count(BTNode *node){
   if(node==NULL) return 0;
   return count(node->left)+1+count(node->right);//you may optimize it
}

void* getFromBT(BTNode* bt, int index) {
    if(count(bt->left)>index) return getFromBT(bt->left,index);
    if(index>count(bt->left) && index<=count(bt)) return bt;
    else return getFromBT(bt->right,index-(count(bt->left)+1);//assuming bt is 1
}
```

I have not tested it, but this logic will work.